# Selenium VBA FindElement Object Required Error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm learning selenium vba and this particular line is driving me nuts.

```
bot.FindElement(By.ClassName("UserHours-Button1")).Click
```

It's giving me error 424: Object Required. Anything wrong with the syntax?

Comment: your shown method syntax is not vba

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the first instance then

```
bot.FindElementByClass("UserHours-Button1")).Click
```

Assuming you are using Selenium basic wrapper for VBA. Otherwise, please update question with further info.